# Getting a 404 error while trying to post data into db

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am able to upload a csv file, which has only one column per row. Now i want to read the contents of file and pass it as data to the ajax. My code till now:

```
var addPortfolio = function(){
            console.log("In adding portfolio");
            var myURL = "/dashboard/btnAdd?sid=" + sid;

            var symbols = ('#uploadSymList')[0].value;
            console.log("Symbols="+symbols);
            var data={};
                data["symbols"] = symbols;
//          
            console.log("Going for an ajax call");

            var call_obj = {
                url: myURL,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                return_data: true,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("Successful request/response sent");
//                  processSymbols(data);
                },
            error : function(data) {
                    // alert("Some Error");
                    showErrorMessage("Error: Could not load to the DB.");
                }   
            };
   call_obj();
}
```

Comment: does /dashboard/btnAdd` exist on your server? either as a physical script, or something for a rewrite to catch?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get `call_obj is not a function` ?

Comment: Where do you actually make the AJAX call? `call_obj` is an object, not a function. You need to actually call `$.ajax()` and pass `call_obj` to it as the first parameter.

Comment: I made the change by passing the call_obj as parameter, still the same error though.

Comment: I want to read the contents of the uploaded file and insert those in the db using the ajax post

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you don't call an Ajax request, instead you creating an object literal without any function. Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    return_data: true,
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Successful request/response sent");
//                  processSymbols(data);
    },
error : function(data) {
        // alert("Some Error");
        showErrorMessage("Error: Could not load to the DB.");
    }   
});
```

Or:

```
$.ajax(call_obj);
```